# Is it possible to prevent eth0 network traffic from accessing eth1 network?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, network-interface

I am not really sure how this is possible but I have a linux(ubuntu 14.04) box with 2 interfaces. eth0 is connected to our lan `192.168.0.*` and eth1 is connected to a dlink wifi router on network `192.168.3.*` .

Wifi network is only available for mobile devices. They are only supposed to access a web application installed on the box. I want to prevent any eventualities such as accessing 192.168.0.* network even if someone gets authorized access to the box via ssh.

Is something like that possible?

**EDIT**

In /etc/sysctl.conf I have now `net.ipv4.ip_forward=0` with sudo -p /etc/sysctl.conf with a restart of the machine. But it didn't work. I can ping 192.168.0.* network

```
#sysctl -a
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.all.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.tag = 0
```

**EDIT 2**

below is my iptables

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Just turn off `ip_forward`, so traffic from two networks can not reach others.

Comment: thanks for your comments. /etc/sysctl.conf that is right? is it safer as opposed to iptables? search about turning off ip_forward led me to this post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2087828

Comment: It depends on your purpose, if your server was not used as a router, turn off `ip_forward` is enough and simple.

Comment: I updated my answer. And it's not a router.

Comment: How about your iptables rule?

Comment: it's blank at the moment. updated the post

Comment: If someone gets ssh access to the box which is connected to both networks, you can't stop them from talking to all networks that box is on.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to zero should prevent access your LAN network from any device behind the `eth1`. But you can't prevent anyone who accessed your box, if he has root access. Use iptables `filter` table and `input` or `output` chain to prevent non-root users who accessed the box from accessing you lan.